# How can we prove that $N_G(H)=H$ implies $N_{f(G)}(f(H))=f(H)$

Tags: group-theory

Let $f:G\to K$ be a surjective group homomorphism and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ satisfying $N_G(H)=H$. Then $N_K(f(H))=f(H)$.

I'm trying to prove or disprove it. perhaps, this proposition is true. But, how can we prove it?

Edit: I thought it is true because WIKI said it is true without proof
https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Self-normalizing_subgroup

Comment: This is false, but it does not seem to be very easy to think of counterexamples. I can think of one of order $2688$ with structure $2^4:L_3(2)$, $H \cong L_3(2)$ and $K = L_3(2) \times C_2$, but perhaps there are easier examples.

Comment: @Derek Holt Thanks for comment. But could you please give $G$ and $f$ in your counterexample? Perhaps you already told me, but maybe I didn't understand because I didn't know the Projective special linear group well.

Comment: Related, but specifically for finite groups: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4090288/image-of-a-self-normalizing-subgroup-under-a-surjective-homomorphism

Comment: There is a similar but smaller counterexample of order $1920$ with structure $2^5:A_5$, which has the advantage that it is in the small groups library, so can be accessed easily from GAP or Magma. I will answer the related question and give more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false, so the groupprops article is incorrect.

For example, every group is the homomorphic image of some free group, and in free groups there are *lots* of self-normalising subgroups. In particular, maximal cyclic subgroups are self-normalising (and every non-trivial element is contained in a maximal cyclic subgroup). So you just need to find a group $G$ which contains a cyclic subgroup which is not self-normalising.

So, getting specific, consider any surjective homomorphism $\phi:F(a, b)\twoheadrightarrow K_4$ the Klein $4$-group. Then $\langle a\rangle$ is self-normalising, but $\phi(\langle a\rangle)$ is normal.

---

What *is* true is that if $H\lhd G$ and $\phi:G\twoheadrightarrow K$ then $\phi(H)\lhd K$. But that's a separate question.

Comment: That's right. It is the easy counterexample which makes my question a stupid one. Thank you.

Comment: @PMJ Since you found the assertion on the grouprops webpage, the self-appointed MSE jury finds you not guilty of the egregious crime of asking a stupid question :) I have attempted to report the error to groupprops.