# Image of a self-normalizing subgroup under a surjective homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

I'm trying to prove that an image of a self-normalizing subgroup of a finite group under a surjective homomorphism is again self-normalizing in the target group.

I proved that if the following is true then the statement above is also true.

If *H* is a self-normalizing subgroup of a finite group *G* and *N* is a normal subgroup of *G*, then *NH* is also a self-normalizing subgroup of *G*.

However, I couldn't figure out why this holds.

Also, these two statement is used in some papers such as "Nilpotent self-normalizing subgroups of soluble groups", but I couldn't find the reference that contains the proof of them.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we prove that $N_G(H)=H$ implies $N_{f(G)}(f(H))=f(H)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4090186/how-can-we-prove-that-n-gh-h-implies-n-fgfh-fh)

Comment: @CalvinKhor In the question that you are linking to, the question being asked  here is answered only briefly in a comment (by me), which is why I have answered it here.

Comment: @DerekHolt thanks for the comment, I have retracted the vote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is false.

To look for a counterexample, we could look for semidirect products $S = N \rtimes H$ with $N$ elementary abelian such that $C_N(H)=1$, for which $N$ has more than one conjugacy class of complements in $S$.

In this situation, $S$ has outer automorphisms $\alpha$ that permute these complements, and so we might hope to find an example $G = S \rtimes \langle \alpha \rangle$, in which the subgroup $H$ is self-normlaizing, but its image in $G/N$ is not.

For one such an example, we can start with $S = N \rtimes H$ with $|N|=2^4$ and $H \cong A_5$, where the action of $A_5$ on $N$ is that of ${\rm SL}(2,4) \cong A_5$ on its natural module. Then $|H^1(S,N)|= 4$, and we can construct a group $S \rtimes \langle \alpha \rangle$, where $\alpha$ is an automorphism of order $2$ that interchanges two non-conjugate complements of $N$ in $S$.

The group $G$ is $\mathtt{SmallGroup}(1920,240995)$ in the GAP/Magma databases. The subgroup $H$ is isomorphic to $A_5$ and $N$ is the unique normal subgroup of order $2^4$, so you can easily check the claimed properties.

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought it is true since https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Self-normalizing_subgroup says it is true without any proof or reference